# Python using pyad to display attributes, not getting logonHours

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, pyad

I've been trying to get `logonHours` to display, while using the `pyad` in **Python 3.7**. When I go to display logonHours, as an output it gives me 
`memory at 0x0000000003049708` etc.

Not sure how to display that data.  All other attributes displays properly.

```
from pyad import *
q = pyad.adsearch.ADQuery()
q.execute_query(
    attributes= ["distinguishedName", "givenName", "userWorkstations","homeDirectory", "homeDrive", "logonHours"],
    where_clause = "objectClass = '*'",
    base_dn = "OU=Graphic Design Students, DC=someplace, DC=com"
)
adoutput = []
for row in q.get_results():
    adoutput.append(row["distinguishedName"])
    adoutput.append(row["givenName"])
    adoutput.append(row["userWorkstations"])
    adoutput.append(row["homeDirectory"])
    adoutput.append(row["homeDrive"])
    adoutput.append(row["logonHours"])
adoutput = [x for x in adoutput if x != None]

print(adoutput)
```

my output looks like:

```
<memory at 0x0000000003049708>
<memory at 0x00000000030497C8>
<memory at 0x0000000003049888>
<memory at 0x0000000003049948>
<memory at 0x0000000003049A08>
<memory at 0x0000000003049AC8>
```

Comment: So it's not just the `logonHours` that is messed up? It looks like all of them are? Try just `print(row["distinguishedName"])` and see if that gives you the proper data. Maybe it's just getting messed up in your array. (I don't know python very well)

Comment: 'print(row["distinguishedName"])' shows up just fine, as well as the other attributes.  logonHours is the only one outputing as a memory location.  I'm figuring that the 'logonHours' is coming out as some object that is being displayed as a memory location.  Still trying to get it in some usable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
row["logonHours"].tobytes()
```

to get the byte value -- you'll see the same fairly cryptic thing that ADSIEdit shows for the attribute value.

The trick then is turning it into something *not* cryptic. There's a good explanation of how the value is encoded at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/545552d4-8daf-4dd8-8291-6f088f35c2a4/how-is-the-logon-hours-attribute-set-in-active-directory-windows-server-2008-r2-?forum=winserverDS

Answer (score 0):

LogonHours is a COM object.

Here is how I handle the logonHours attribute. In my loop, I check the data type:

```
import pyad.pyadutils
import win32com.client
if isinstance(v, win32com.client.CDispatch):
    value = pyad.pyadutils.convert_datetime(v)
```

This gives me a datetime object that I can work with. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/545552d4-8daf-4dd8-8291-6f088f35c2a4/how-is-the-logon-hours-attribute-set-in-active-directory-windows-server-2008-r2-?forum=winserverDS#7c102b98-1182-4c05-b236-28fc4784effb) linked in @LisaJ's answer, here are some applications you can use this attribute for. Hopefully this helps someone out.

```
#Convert the array to a list of which hours each day the account is logged in
weekList = []
for shift_1, shift_2, shift_3 in zip(*[iter(row["logonHours"].tobytes())]*3):
    weekList.append(format(shift_1, '08b') + format(shift_2, '08b') + format(shift_3, '08b'))

#Total the hours for each day
totalHours = {}
for i, (shift_1, shift_2, shift_3) in enumerate(zip(*[iter(row["logonHours"].tobytes())]*3)):
    totalHours[i] = len((format(shift_1, '08b') + format(shift_2, '08b') + format(shift_3, '08b')).replace("0", ""))
```